# I have message intents enabled but message.content is still giving me a blank result. What's wrong?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a bot with discord.py and message.content is not giving anything. I have the message intents enabled in the developer portal. What could be the issue?

I tried to run my code and get a response from the bot but it won't respond with anything and when I try to print messge.content it shows nothing.

```
import discord
from random import choice

TOKEN = (Not including this)

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

#Generates a random answer word
with open('answers.txt','r') as f:
    word = choice(f.readlines())

#Prints when Bot is online
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    user_message = str(message.content)
    print(username,user_message)
    #Skip if its the bot's own message
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('hi'):
        await message.channel.send(f'Hi {username}, you said {user_message}')
        return

#Runs Bot
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have it enabled. I'm pretty sure you messed up `message_content` with `members`. In your code it says

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
```

not

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
```

Also, make sure that the `message_content` intent are enabled on your application. You can enable it [here](https://discord.com/developers), by clicking your application, going to the `Bot` tab on the left, scrolling down and enabling the required intent(s).